# Why are so many of my files executable?

Tags: linux, cygwin

Many of the files in my home directory are executable for no good reason.

By 'executable' I mean that the -x flag is set (as shown by **ls -al**). When I write the file name, my shell completes the file name on tabbing.

This includes many PDF files, HTML files, and image files. I would never consider these to be executable. Trying to execute them produces error messages (I suppose) such as 'no job control'.

Why is the executable flag set, apparently be default, for so many files? I should mention that I am using Cygwin, but I have observed similar behavior on other machines (proper Linux) as well.

Comment: This is definitely not normal for "proper Linux" (which Cygwin isn't, because Windows permissions are entirely different).

Comment: which home directory, Windows one or cygwin home ?

Comment: @matzeri: I have been looking at my home directory in Cygwin.

Comment: @slhck: It seems that most of the files in the windows file systems are considered executable by Cygwin. Even if they are created only via the shell.

Comment: check `umask` value. With normal `0022` the file created by cygwin programs should not be executable